# Sierra, cpp command throwing 'iostream' file not found

Tags: c++, xcode, clang, iostream

I'm following a [tutorial](http://www.icepp.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~sakamoto/education/atlasj/cplusplus/l1.html) on my macbook pro with Sierra and Xcode9.0.1

I compiled the following hello world code with g++ without problems.

```
#include <iostream>
main() {
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
}
```

But when I execute

```
cpp hello.cxx | more
```

as required by the tutorial, I got the following error message:

```
hello.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
# 1 "hello.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 330 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "hello.cpp" 2
```

Comment: The `cpp` command is the preprocessor. It might not by itself know where system header files are located. You probably need to use the `-I` (upper-case i) option to specify the system header file search paths.

Comment: After googling I found that [`cpp`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/cpp.htm) is the name for the c pre-processor in Linux and probably also in OS/X. (As it does only pre-processing (e.g. statements prefixed `#`) it will work with C++ files as well.) May be, you try `man cpp` to find out more. It possibly doesn't have the right include directories per default. To check this you could try `cpp -I` and the path where file `iostream` is located.

Comment: Thanks, so following your comment I tried this: cpp -I /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream hello.cpp

But got: 
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'c'
clang: warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a working `g++` compiler, you may use the following command line for getting the preprocessed output:

`g++ -E hello.cxx | more`

The `-E` option instructs the compiler driver to execute the preprocessor and emit the preprocessed output.